# Rendering lots of smaller objects in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Greetings each and all.

I've been struggling with OpenGL ES 2.0 and a particular problem for the last few days now. I'm looking to implement a Geometry Wars clone, for the iPhone, for fun and to learn this technology. So, my background in 3d programming is fairly good, although mainly concentrated around vector mathematics rather then draw calls towards the graphical API, as I've been working with DirectX on and off for the last couple of years. The problem, however, is that I've mainly been working with bigger meshes, loading, translating and transforming them in several ways and now I find myself in a position where I want to handle small meshes, and lots of them.

The objects are triangles, rectangles, hexagons etc. and I want the ability to modify them all separately (eg making the other edge wavy or pulsating). When I've worked with multiple big meshes I've made separate draw calls for them, easily attaching shaders and their respective parameters, but in this case I would like to render it all in one call and there's where my knowledge fails me.

So, to clearify my question. How are you to modify small meshes, preferably stored in one vertex array, individually and render them all at once using shaders with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Although code examples are more then welcome, a "simple" explanation would be enough to get me started. I assume I'm missing something trivial here and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Karl

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like [Instancing](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_instanced.txt) (and [instanced arrays](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/instanced_arrays.txt)) can be an answer to your problem, although it might be a bit too advanced for iOS or ES in general to be supported. This way you can render many copies of the same geometry with per instance data (like a specific texture index or sub-texture or shader parameters). But of course, you cannot render different objects with completely different shaders in one draw call.

Otherwise the much simpler (and maybe much less optimized) function `glMultiDrawArrays/Elements` renders multiple completely different geometries in one call, but you cannot tell which triangle belongs to which object in the shader and I also doubt that it gives that much of a performance boost.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer!  From what I've read and understood, which is in line with your assumption, ES does not support instancing and with the fact that the shader isn't aware of what object are being rendered, thanks for pointing that out, I've decided to go for a more brute force approach. For the time being I'll render each object separately with hope that I'll be able to optimize this further down the road.  Thanks again!

Comment: One way of faking instancing is to add an id to your attribute stream, and then have the per-instance data as uniforms. This will not be the prettiest thing out there, but it should work and you should be able to minimize the number of drawcalls you have.